# How do I get a Twilio function to continue a call and return gather information

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions

I have a studio flow that I am attempting to handle multiple different languages. I have a widget that starts the call and then passes it over to my function. However, after making the call and moving to the function, the call instantly ends. Am I doing something incorrect? From what I understand, I can send the call to a function to continue it. Is something wrong with my function? See my function code below.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  const gatherOptions = { Numdigit:"1", Timeout:"5"};
  let sayOptions = { Voice:"Alice", Language: event.Language };

  if(!event.Retries){
    event.Retries = 0;
  }
  console.log(event.Language);
  console.log(event.Body);
  if (event.Digits) {
    if(event.Digits === '9' && event.Retries < 3) {
      event.Retries += 1;
      twiml.gather(gatherOptions).say(sayOptions, event.Body);
    } else if(event.Digits === '3' || event.Digits === '5'){
      return callback(null, twiml);
    }else {
      twiml.say("sorry, I didnt get that.");
      event.Digits = '9';
    }
  } else {
    twiml.gather(gatherOptions).say(sayOptions, event.Body);
  }
  callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Comment: Hi Nemean, welcome to SO! Are there any error messages in the [Twilio Debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/debugger) when executing this? What are you trying to do with this function?

Comment: There were a few errors (in the options) and i have cleared them up and started getting some voice. now I am attempting to get back the response.

I am attempting to use a function to be able to do the following:
1. Allow for multiple languages with only 1 widget
2. Gather and send responses back to my studio flow. (9 repeats the message, 3 or 5 are accepted answers, anything else is a repeat)

Answer (score 0):

Outside of your Twilio Function code, anytime you jump out of Studio and return TwiML and then want to return to the Studio flow, you must use the [TwiML Redirect Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/twiml-redirect) (which you can use to call the Twilio Function).

> > Your gatherOptions keys should be [camelCase](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather) (i.e. numDigits, timeout).

This may be useful to carry state across Functions.

[How to Share Information Between Your Applications](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/how-share-information-between-your-applications)

Comment: Thanks! Ill see what i can do with that widget and check into that second link!